# SpringBoot does not resolve @Value properties without PropertySource annotation

Tags: spring-boot

I have a bunch of `@Value` annotated fields in a SpringBoot configuration file, with the matching values in the standard application.properties . If I don't annotate the configuration file `with @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` it will just copy the "${prop1}" string into the actual variable.

I tried adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to the @Configuration class (instead of the PropertySource annotation), but all it does is to break when a requested property is not found.

SpringBoot is supposed to resolve the properties automatically from the standard `application.properties` file, why this behaviour? Using version 2.2.2.RELEASE

**Update:**

The answers are correct, the reason it was not working was that I was calling these properties in a test. Annotating the test with **`@SpringBootTest`** fixes the issue. In fact when the application is running it is **`@SpringBootApplication`** that does the magic

Comment: Can you add your configuration file and the class where you want to inject the value? Spring Boot should resolve automatically properties in ``application.properties`` file.

Comment: Do you have the main method marked as `@SpringBootApplication`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in [this article (chapter 5)](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring), SpringBoot manage automatically the `application.properties` file.

I don't know if this is your problem because I've not seen the code, but in Spring Boot the `Application` class should be annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Take a look at  [this starting example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

---

You can then inject the value for example in a controller class in this way:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Value("${test}")
    private String test;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    String hello() {
        return test;
    }

}
```